# C: Passing an arbitrary sized array to a function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to write a C program which reads input from a text file and puts it into a 2D-array where Rows are lines and columns are characters.

However I am confused after reading the following article:

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

The function definition which I am thinking of is

```
int processArray(char **text) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

where I am attempting to pass in a pointer to a 2D array whose dimensions I don't know until runtime. I would like to be able to access the elements using two square brackets [] []

However in the link it says the following:

> An intermediate pointer would have to be used when attempting to call
>   it with a two-dimensional array:
>
> ```
> extern g(int **ipp);
> int *ip = &array[0][0];
> g(&ip);       /* PROBABLY WRONG */
> ```
>
> but this usage
>   is misleading and almost certainly incorrect, since the array has been
>   ``flattened'' (its shape has been lost).

1. What is wrong with the above declaration?
2. How should you define an array to multiple dimensions?

Comment: `int processArray(int r, int c, char text[r][c]);` .....`processArray(ROWS, COLS, matrix);` Take a look at [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)s

Comment: Something like `int **` is **not** a 2D array and cannot be used as one! It is a completely different datatype. The text is indeed missleading and wrong as it stands. Note that K&R is outdated since 18 years.

Comment: That is what I was fearing, how do you do this? Note: VLA is one option for this, how can I achieve it otherwise? Could you also explain why a int ** is not a 2D array?

Comment: Because it just isn't.  It's a pointer.  It's size is fixed.  It has no storage in itself.  It is not an array.  Pointers are not arrays.  Arrays of pointers can point to sparse data with gaps. That is because such data is not in an array.  An array has no gaps, has storage and is not a pointer.

Comment: Okay I understand, I would like to pass a pointer to an array of arbitrary size so that I do not have to copy the entire array onto the stack and have the ability to index it using two [] []

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: you ca use a simple pointer and then `*(pointer+selected_col+(selected_row*MAX_COL))`

Comment: 2D arrays in C and C++ soon casue trouble. Your best bet is to flatten and pass everything around as a 1D array with width, height and if necessary depth.

Comment: Since we're discussing storing text, which typically has lines of varying length, wouldn't a 2D array of char be rather wasteful compared to the `char **` form?

Comment: Yes I agree so maybe a 2D array is not what I need. Also as indicated above, probably a 1D array of char * (strings)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside VLAs you can use a simple pointer to point your matrix:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAX_ROWS 2
#define MAX_COLS 2

void test (int *matrix, int col_max, int row_max)
{
    for (int i=0; i<row_max; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<col_max; j++)
        {
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]= %d\n", i, j, *(matrix+(i*col_max)+j) );
        }
    }

}
int main(void)
{
    int matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };

    test(&matrix[0][0], MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS);

    return 0;
}
```